# SSHD configuration,authenticity of localhost can't be established

Tags: ssh

If I try this

```
ssh jh@jh-System-Product-Name
```

Works fine.

```
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.10.0-40-generic x86_64)

 * Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
 * Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
 * Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage
```

On the other hand

```
ssh localhost
The authenticity of host 'localhost (127.0.0.1)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:gsLR5X+7Im1MdPch7u8Jlvm0ql6PH0rDBsWnpOpizd4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? no
```

What does this mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Short Answer

It means either/or:

- you've never connected to the local system via `ssh`.
- new host keys have been generated on your system.

#### Longer Answer to include information from the comments

[SSH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell) is a [Trust On First Use (TOFU)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trust_on_first_use) system.  This means that the connecting system has a list of known hosts that it will always trust.  If a previously unknown remote connection is made, the remote system's host key is presented for the connecting user to inspect and accept or reject.  If the new host is accepted, that host key gets added to the local list of known hosts that is always trusted.

This is SSH's most vulnerable area.  [DNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System) lookups are unsecured for most domains unless [DNSSEC](http://www.dnssec.net/) is deployed. So, there is a possibility of an attacker spoofing DNS to look like the remote system.  In this case, the host key would not match, but many users don't bother to check the host keys anyway.  So, if using SSH with password authentication, a remote attacker can Man-In-The-Middle (MITM) an SSH connection and intercept your username and password if the host keys are incorrect and the connecting user doesn't bother to check.

There is a mitigating DNS record called `sshfp`, which stands for SSH Fingerprint.  The [`sshfp` record](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSHFP_record) is entered by the domain owner in the DNS zone file.  A connecting system to the domain checks for `sshfp` records.  If a record is found, the fingerprint is verified.  This prevents a connecting system from connecting to the incorrect remote host in the TOFU trust model.  However, many, maybe most, DNS providers do not support the `sshfp` record type.  And so, most `ssh` connections are not protected against DNS spoofing.

So, be careful when connecting to a remote system that you have connected to previously but presents a new host key.  Your concerned response is good.  However, in this case, most likely unwarranted.

Comment: Generated by whom,by me?

Comment: ssh keeps a list of known hosts...  I get the same error, because I don't use ssh to connect to `localhost` ... there's generally no reason to do that.

Comment: @MikiBelavista, generated by whoever manages the system, possibly you.  However, in all likelikhood the issue is the first bullet point: you've never done this before.  `ssh` by default issues this warning the first time you connect to any hostname, and this is likely the first time you connected to `localhost` from that machine.

Comment: @user4556274 Desktops is mine,so I am admin.

Comment: @RubberStamp Can I see somehow list of a known hosts?

Comment: @MikiBelavista `~/.ssh/known_hosts` will have a list of finger prints, etc.

Comment: @MikiBelavista, note that if _hostname hashing_ is configured, you will not be able to (visually) match any given fingerprint in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` to a specific host.  If _hostname hashing_ is not enabled, or you have an older `ssh` which did not support hashing, you'll see all hostnames in plaintext along with their key fingerprints.